# Python program to find the intersection points for two line graphs in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, statistics

I have a code to try and print the intersection point of two graphs and the graph itself. For some reason, it doesn't print the right intersection point for the x-axis and it prints the one for the line of best fit of the graph. I want it to print for the exact intersection point but I can't make it work. I have my code below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import linregress
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

E = [113.3, 86.8, 74.6, 55.751, 46.147, 38.793]
L = [7.06, 8.06, 9.06, 10.06, 11.06, 12.06]


plt.plot(L, E)

plt.axhline(60, color='r', linestyle='-')
slope, intercept, _, _, _ = linregress(L, E)

# Calculate the intersection point
x_intercept = (60 - intercept) / slope
y_intercept = 60

print("Intersection point coordinates: ({}, {})".format(x_intercept, y_intercept))

plt.show()
```

It gives me this as the output:

[Energy vs Quantum Well Width with the x and y intercept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3NC2.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating the intersection between your horizontal line and the fitted line, not the original plot itself. This becomes more clear if you plot the fitted line. Add this to your code to see how your fitted line compares to your data.

```
x = np.arange(7, 12, 0.1)
yfit = slope * x + intercept
plt.plot(x, yfit, '--')
```